# Proguard comes out of the box in android Studio? What does it means?

Tags: android, proguard

I was reading an article about Proguard in Android Studio their is a line

> Proguard comes out of the box in android Studio

Can anyone please explain this to me? If you are interested to read the completed article I'll put the link below.

[Article Link](https://blog.mindorks.com/applying-proguard-in-an-android-application)

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that proguard is bundled together with your default android project and you do not need to download it from outside via gradle or maven

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true// Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true// Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Ref:[More on proguard usage in android](https://medium.com/gradeup/demystifying-proguard-a-simplified-guide-to-understanding-and-integrating-proguard-in-your-fd3accae3238)